# In TCL how do I include packages/libaries which are not located in the "lib" folder of the interpreter ?

Tags: include, tcl

Usually when I need a certain package in TCL I simply use the "require packagename" command. This however requires that the called libary files to be located in the lib folder of the interpreter in order to be found.

In my case I do not have access to this folder. So, how can I use the require command or alike when the called libary is located somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lappend auto_path /path/to/package
```

http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M4

Comment: I believe you can also set the `TCLLIBPATH` environment variable to influence where things are looked for.